# Using Python Twisted Web HTTPChannel vs Resource

Tags: python, encryption, twisted.web

I have a specific protocol specification I am writing to that utilizes a [Station to Station Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station-to-Station_protocol) for authentication.  Thus far I've been using Twisted web and the [Resource](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.resource.Resource.html) class along with `render_GET`, `render_POST`, but once the authentication step is complete with my client the communication is encrypted, even at the HTTP protocol level.  That is I lose visibility to `GET /resource` and only receive encrypted bytes on the TCP session.  I tried looking at intercepting the `render` method but it is not called if there is no HTTP method parsed.  Is it possible to use `Resource` still or do I need to "downshift" to using [HTTPChannel](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.http.HTTPChannel.html) and its ability to hand me raw data?